# Excel User Input a Number and Goes to Matching Number in Another Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to create a user dialog box where the user enters a number and gets taken to that matching number in another worksheet? Here is what I mean:

Worksheet 1

3.3
3.4
3.5
3.6

Worksheet 2
3.3 Jon
3.4 Bryan
3.5 Ken
3.6 David

The user clicks to start a macro and the dialog box comes up:

Enter a number:

User enters 3.4, for example, and gets taken to the spot where 3.4 is in Worksheet 2.

Is there a VBA function I can create to do this?

Comment: `Application.Match()` will work in this case.

Comment: Both VBA and data validation combined with formulas can achieve this. What's the next step after finding the target value in Worksheet2?

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub SearchAndSelect()

Dim searchTerm As String
Dim foundCell As Range

searchTerm = InputBox("Enter search term:", "Search")

If searchTerm Is Empty Then Exit Sub

Set foundCell = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.Find(What:=searchTerm)

If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
    foundCell.Select
Else
    MsgBox "The search term was not found.", vbInformation
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Find By Number in Legal Numbering

```vb
Sub FindByNumber()

    ' Define constants.

    Const IB_PROMPT As String = "Please enter the number"
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Find By Number"
    Const SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet2"
    Const SCROLL_TO_CELL As Boolean = True
    Const REMOVE_TRAILING_DOT As Boolean = False
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Check worksheet.
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(SHEET_NAME)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No worksheet named """ & SHEET_NAME & """ in workbook """ _
            & wb.Name & """ found!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Not ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
        MsgBox "Cannot select on the hidden sheet """ & ws.Name _
            & """ in workbook """ & wb.Name & """!", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Receive input.
    
    Dim iStr As String: iStr = InputBox(IB_PROMPT, PROC_TITLE)
    
    Dim sLen As Long: sLen = Len(iStr)
    
    If sLen = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Canceled.", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Process the input string.
    
    Dim Char As String, n As Long, bStr As String, DotFound As Boolean
    
    ' Find first digit.
    Do Until Char Like "#"
        n = n + 1
        If n > sLen Then
            MsgBox "No digits found in """ & iStr & """!", _
                vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Char = Mid(iStr, n, 1)
    Loop
    iStr = Right(iStr, sLen - n + 1)
        
    sLen = sLen - n + 1
    bStr = Left(iStr, 1) ' write first digit
    n = 2
    
    ' Remove if not digit or dot
    Do Until n > sLen
        Char = Mid(iStr, n, 1)
        If Char Like "#" Then ' is a digit
            bStr = bStr & Char
            DotFound = False
        ElseIf Char = "." Then ' is a dot
            If Not DotFound Then ' no double dots allowed
                bStr = bStr & Char
                DotFound = True
            End If
        'Else ' neither
        End If
        n = n + 1
    Loop
        
    If REMOVE_TRAILING_DOT Then
        If Right(bStr, 1) = "." Then bStr = Left(bStr, Len(bStr) - 1)
    End If
        
    ' Find the cell.
    
    Dim cell As Range:
    Set cell = ws.Cells.Find(bStr & "*", , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows)
    
    If cell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The number """ & bStr & """ was not found.", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    ' Select the cell.
    
    If Not wb Is ActiveWorkbook Then wb.Activate
    Application.Goto Reference:=cell, Scroll:=SCROLL_TO_CELL

End Sub
```